# for variable within .getJSON displayed wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, console.log

I have the following code (javascript/jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){

        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

console log:

```
3
Object { stream: Object, _links: Object }
3
Object { stream: Object, _links: Object }
3
Object { stream: Object, _links: Object }
```

isn't it true, that `console.log(i);` should log 0 in the first loop, 1 in the second and 2 in the third? But somehow it always returns 3 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        (function (index) {
            $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data) {
                console.log(index);
                console.log(data);
            });
        })(i)
    }
});
```

Comment: This happens as the for loop executes completely before AJAX gets triggered and the state is maintained in the code for the variable **i**. Using closures and anonymous function to maintain the state of i during the execution of the for loop.

Comment: thank you! it worked perfectly even tho I don't understand what you did. How is this procedure called ; is there literature about this?

Comment: @orly Read the first link in the comments under your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ecma6 then you can use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to avoid closure issue.
It create block scoping.

```
$(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

otherwise,You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
$(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        (function(i) {

            $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(data);
            });

        })(i)

    }
});
```

Similary,you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

Can you display result in $.getJson success?

```
 $(function(){
            $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data){
              for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                console.log(i);
                console.log(data[i]);
               }
            });
        });
```

Your i=3 because your loop does not wait $.getJson success. It is working and increment values without delay.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```js
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });

    $(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/esl_csgo", function(data){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He can "try this", but he should never use it. Making these Ajax requests synchronous is not necessary (at least in this case), and it may freeze the webpage while waiting for the responses.