# console.log(i) inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, console.log

I have a problem, I don't know why if I call `tab[4]()` or any other number <0,9> the result in the console is always 10.
I was guessing the result for `i` would be `i`

```
var tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tab[i] = function(){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `i`. `i` is `10` when you run the function. You have a for loop that increments it every time you go around the loop until it gets to 10 and the loop stops.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944850/for-variable-within-getjson-displayed-wrong/38944865#38944865

Comment: A good explanation to this can be found here: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/3-questions-to-watch-out-for-in-a-javascript-interview-725012834ccb#c5f5. The easiest solution is to replace `var i = 0` with `let i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tab[i] = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i)
    }
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let a = i;
  tab[i] = function(){
      console.log(a);
  }
}
  
tab[1]();
tab[2]();
```